# Cannot further process the result from useQuery in Vue Apollo (Vue 3, composition API)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-apollo

I have a Vue 3 component that displays some data, fetched through a composable that talks to an API via Apollo. The `useMyQuery` function returns `result` and `loading` from the query, which works fine. It also does a transformation (transformData) on an array from the result object (arrayData). This is the part that doesn't work.

When I run the code as displayed, I get the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data is undefined` (I assume because when it first runs, `useQuery` hasn't returned anything yet. But if I wrap the content of the `transformData`-function like `if (!data) {return null} else {...}`, it never seems to update, it just returns null.

I wonder if this is because I am running the function only on the `result.arrayData`, which is not reactive? In that case, how can I make this work?

The composable:

```js
// useMyQueries.js
import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export function useMyQuery() {
    const variables = {
        'search': "hello",
        'limit': 0
    }
    const { result, loading } = useQuery(gql(QUERY), variables)

    function transformData(data) {
        return {
            labels: data.map(item => item.time),
            datasets: [{ data: data.map(item => item.count) }]
        };

    }
    return {
        result,
        loading,
        transformedData: transformData(result.arrayData),
    }
}
```

The component:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-card title="Title" :loading="loading">
            <v-card-text>
                {{ transformedData }}
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useMyQuery } from '@/useMyQueries.js'

const { result, loading, transformedData } = useMyQuery()

</script>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to wait until `useQuery` has executed. Have a look at the `onResult` handler on the result object.